# nginx with different port for https

Tags: nginx, server, https, localhost, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm facing an issue where the default HTTPS port, 443, is already in use. I switched it to port 444, but now my website can only be accessed via 'https://example.com:444' when I try to access my website via 'https://example.com,' it's not working . How can I configure it to work without explicitly specifying the port?

this is my nginx.conf

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  example.com www.example.com;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;

        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
        
        

    }


    # HTTPS server
    #
    server {
        #listen 444 ssl http2 default_server;
        #listen [::]:444 ssl http2 default_server;

        listen 444 ssl;

        server_name  example.com www.example.com;

# Disable root application access. You may want to allow this in development.
  #location ~ ^/$ {
   # return 404;
  #}

        ssl_certificate      C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ssl\wildcard24.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ssl\wildcard24.pem;
        
        ssl_password_file   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ssl\psw.txt;
        
        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;


}

}


}
```

i expecting to work without explicitly specifying the port?

Is it possible to configure my server to listen on port 443 and ensure that all requests, including the root URL (https://example.com) and subpaths (e.g., https://example.com/map), are redirected to the desired pages on the same port, eliminating the need to specify port numbers in the URLs?

Comment: You can't. Browsers assume https defaults to port 443, if you're not running the https on port 443 you must specify the port explicitly.

Comment: Is it possible to configure my server to listen on port 443 and ensure that all requests, including the root URL (https://example.com) and subpaths (e.g., https://example.com/map), are redirected to the desired pages on the same port, eliminating the need to specify port numbers in the URLs??

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS URLs assume a default port of 443. (Historically HTTP URLs assumed 80).

If something is running on port 444, you can't access it without the a URL that explicitly states that port number.

If this is more a concern about bookmarking and convenience (rather than hiding appearance of the port number must be explicit), admins will often configure the 443 server to re-direct to the 444 server (https://example.com/other_server -> https://example.com:443/)

There are other ways for a more serious solution, that's more like "server fault" (the admin/config) stack exchange.

Comment: Is it possible to configure my server to listen on port 443 and ensure that all requests, including the root URL (https://example.com) and subpaths (e.g., https://example.com/map), are redirected to the desired pages on the same port, eliminating the need to specify port numbers in the URLs

Comment: For this web server, I don't know. If you want an old-school solution, you'd run the two apps on different ports and a reverse web proxy on 443.